# Importing SVG files in matlab

Tags: matlab, svg

I'm looking for a library for importing / exporting SVG files in matlab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/7401) is a package which claims to export figures to SVG format.